# What are the financial incentives for running an accuser

Tags: accuser

It's quite clear what the financial incentives are for running a baker and endorser.

I couldn't find any information on why someone would have an incentive to run an accuser.

What are the incentives for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If two endorsements are made for the same slot or two blocks at the
>   same height by a delegate, the evidence can be collected by an accuser
>   and included in a block for a period of PRESERVED_CYCLES, including
>   the current cycle.
>
> This accusation forfeits the entirety of the safety deposit and future
>   reward up to that point in the cycle. Half is burned, half goes to the
>   accuser in the form of a block reward.

https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html#accusations

Your incitation is to get half the safety deposit in case of a correct accusation. The baker of the block including the accusation get the reward. There is no incentive to accuse if you are not able to bake a block. The accuser and the baker are the same entity for a given block.

Note that the return is much predictable than rewards you mentioned.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. For some reason, from my reading I was under the impression the next block baker got the half rewards.

Comment: Is their a bond cost cost required to put up for an accusation? What's the financial incentive to prevent people from accusing everything?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I added some details to clarify. I answered to the second in your other question.

Comment: Thanks @clement-j !