# What is the financial disincentive that prevents accusers from accusing every block?

Tags: accuser

This is really a follow up to my [previous question](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1581/what-are-the-financial-incentives-for-running-an-accuser) which I think may have gotten loss in the comments.

Is there a security deposit required to put up for an accusation? What's the financial incentive to prevent people from accusing every block? It seems like there is big incentive to accuse every block - half of the safety deposit of the baker, which would be 512/2 = 256ꜩ is this correct? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

To accuse someone for double baking, you should provide an evidence. And the evidence is two distinct hashs of two blocks produced at the same level by the baker you'd like to accuse.

So, accusation will not be valid if the baker didn't baked two blocks at the same level.

Comment: Both answers are right, wish we could merge them in to 1 so I could accept it :).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your hypothesis is that a baker could accuse all bakers and endorsers of recent blocks to maximise it changes to hit a bad action.

Detecting behaviors that deserves to be accused is quite simple and based on a tool provided with the node software. There seems to be no gain then to try such a strategy.

Comment: Both answers are right, wish we could merge them in to 1 so I could accept it :).